# how to reposition stage into initial place in kineticjs?

Tags: kineticjs

I am scaling stage using following code

```
var scale = stage.getScale();
    scale.x *= 1.5; //zoomFactor is a global variable
    scale.y *= 1.5;
    stage.setScale(scale);
    stage.setDraggable(true);
    stage.draw();
```

after dragging stage,now I want to reposition stage into initial position with initial scale value by,

```
    var scale = stage.getScale();
    scale.x=1;
    scale.y=1;
    stage.setScale(scale);        
    stage.x = 0;
    stage.y = 0;
    stage.draw();
    stage.setDraggable(false);
```

this code works good for resetting the scale value to initial value but stage is not moved to initial position, Is this correct or I need to make a change the code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the API functions !

```js
  stage.x(0);
  stage.y(0);
```

Or :

```js
  stage.setX(0);
  stage.setY(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save stage positon before scaling first:

```
var scale = stage.getScale();
var stageOriginalX = stage.getPosition().x;
var stageOriginalY = stage.getPosition().y;
    scale.x *= 1.5; //zoomFactor is a global variable
    scale.y *= 1.5;
    stage.setScale(scale);
    stage.setDraggable(true);
    stage.draw();
```

After scaling back, set back original coordinates:

```
var scale = stage.getScale();
scale.x=1;
scale.y=1;
stage.setScale(scale);        
stage.setPosition(stageOriginalX,stageOriginalY);
stage.setDraggable(false);
```